# I have a query on two big tables that is too slow!

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT  t1."TimeS" as TimeS, t1."JobID" as JobID, t1."TaskIndex" as TaskIndex,  t1."MachineID" as MachineID ,t2."EventType" as EventType,  t1."UserName" as UserName, t1."CpuReq" as CpuReq, t1."MemReq" as MemReq, 
  t2."TimeS" as FinTime  , (t2."TimeS"-t1."TimeS") as duration
FROM  scheduled_tasks_table  as t1 ,  public.dead_tasks_table as t2 
     WHERE t1. "TaskIndex"= t2. "TaskIndex"
     AND t1."JobID"= t2."JobID" AND (t2."TimeS"-t1."TimeS")>='0'
```

I have 15GB memory (RAM) and my Config File is:

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 3840MB
effective_cache_size = 11520MB
work_mem = 19660kB
maintenance_work_mem = 960MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

Both my tables both have a single primary key and a single indexe as:( TaskIndex, JobId, Timet)

But this query is really slow:

EXPLAIN:

```
" "Merge Join  (cost=19982628.08..1436656715.61 rows=20251904912 width=105)"
"  Merge Cond: ((t1."TaskIndex" = t2."TaskIndex") AND (t1."JobID" = t2."JobID"))"
"  Join Filter: ((t2."TimeS" - t1."TimeS") >= '0'::bigint)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=12319742.87..12438008.64 rows=47306308 width=93)"
" Sort Key: t1."TaskIndex", t1."JobID""
"  ->  Seq Scan on scheduled_tasks_table t1  (cost=0.00..1438498.08 rows=47306308 width=93)"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=7662858.23..7874671.39 rows=42362632 width=28)"
```

Comment: A properly [formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) output of **`explain (analyze, verbose)`** would be more helpful. And make sure you keep the indention in the plan - that is important. Also show us the _definition_ (=`create index`) of the indexes. Did you try a single index on `("TaskIndex", "JobID", "TimeS")`? Are the columns all of the exact same data type in both tables?

Comment: Actually,  EXPLAIN ANALYSE is also too slow for me. I have a single index on ("TaskIndex", "JobID", "TimeS"), the definition:   `  CREATE INDEX "dead_tasks_table_TimeS_JobID_TaskIndex_idx"
  ON public.dead_tasks_table
  USING btree
  ("TimeS", "JobID", "TaskIndex") `'

Comment: Which are the sizes (row count) of `scheduled_tasks_table` and `dead_tasks_table` and how much time is "really slow"?

Comment: scheduled_tasks_table number of rows: 97,200,000   and  dead_tasks_table number of rows: 48,800,000     ,  the slowness is like: It has been running for 2 days and yet no result!

Comment: Do you still need help with query?

Comment: Actually, my problem remains unsolved, but what I did to get the result I want was Splitting the table into multiple tables by adding a constraint. So at the end instead of 1 table, I got 900 tables.

Answer (score 2):

Probably problem is here:

```
(t2."TimeS"-t1."TimeS")>='0'
```

Postgresql does not use index for this. Can you try just:

```
t2."TimeS" >= t1."TimeS"
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, but I don't think so because even when I remov this condition, the query is still slow.

Comment: When you remove this conditions, as you *broaden* your search, you might probably get many more rows, which would *increase* the timing. So, if feasible, try to test as suggested and evaluate the result...

Comment: I did and the EXPLAIN didn't show many differences.

Comment: How many rows in t2 do you need for each row t1 ? If 1 - you must change your query -- if not : rows=20,251,904,912 . Is too many as for me.

Comment: As mentioned by joanolo you must narrow result of query. Two way - the first do you have many records in t2 for each t1 record? If yes - do you want in result to see all this records or just one last / first? The second way - do you need this big result table or probably you need  some stats?